# AppleWatch Simulator not responding to changes in PushNotificationPayload.apns

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I have my AppleWatch scheme set up for testing notifications like this:

[image: Notification Scheme]

The first time I run the simulator for a given .apns file everythign works great, but say I change the body or title field and run the app again, nothing changes. The simulator will display whatever the original file had. So in order to test new push notification configurations i have to make a new .apns file every single time. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Or is this some sort of xcode bug?

Comment: Which xCode version are you using? no issues on xcode6.2 beta5

Comment: @user1872384 I'm on xCode 6.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,
1) Sometimes happens because you have a bug in the json, and it takes the last valid json.
2) I noticed also that you can't include null in your json, or it will take the last valid json too.
Use this link to verify your payload: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same and I it occurred because I had my changes to the payload JSON file and missed a comma somewhere. Validate your JSON somewhere (such as on http://jsonlint.com/), high odds this is what is happening in your project to.

When I fixed the JSON the issue resolved.